# Best use of mvc calls + thymeleaf

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf, multiple-select

Should I use directly my DAO class (for example UserDao) from thymeleaf template? Or should I use a wrapper (for example; UserDaoController) with all interesting calls to UserDao?

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hibernate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
    List<User> listUsers = userDao.list();

    model.addAttribute("lista", listUsers);
    return "users/users";
    }
```

I am thinking about this, because I need to do 2 selects (for example print all privileges from each user: User -> Roles -> Privilege), and my last thymeleaf is horrible:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Hibernate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hibernate - Users</h1>

    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <h1>Users List</h1>
    <h2><a href="/hibernate/new">New User</a></h2>

    <table border="1">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
        <th>Privileges</th>
        <th>Actions</th>

        <tr th:each="item : ${lista}">
            <td th:text="${item.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${item.username}"></td>
            <td th:text="${item.email}"></td>
            <td>
                <ul th:each="role : ${item.getRoles()}">
                    <li th:text="${role.name}"></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span th:each="role : ${item.getRoles()}">
                    <ul th:each="privi : ${role.getPrivileges()}">
                        <li th:text="${privi.name}"></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/hibernate/edit(id=${item.id})}">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a th:href="@{/hibernate/delete(id=${item.id})}">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about MVC pattern, you should not mix different tiers. Thymeleaf always must get information form the Controller.

In a simple web application, the service tier could (but not should) be mixed with the controller but not with the model one. If you are using this kind of pattern is because the model could change or the view could change but you are always responsible of your logic.

The best usage will be:

- HTML to Controller (no logic, just requests)
- Controller to Service (logic)
- Service to DAO (Abstraction to model access)